# Structured streaming performance and purging the parquet files

Tags: apache-spark, parquet, spark-structured-streaming

I am using Spark structured streaming to get streaming data from Kafka. I need to aggregate various metrics (Say 6 metrics) and write as parquet files. I do see that there is a huge delay between metric 1 and metric 2. For example, if metric 1 is updated recently, metric 2 is one hour old data. How do I improve this performance to work in parallel?

Also, I write Parquet files which should be read by another application. How do I purge old parquet information constantly? Should I have a different application for it?

```java
Dataset<String> lines_topic = spark.readStream().format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", bootstrapServers) 
Dataset<Row> data= lines_topic.select(functions.from_json(lines_topic.col("value"), schema).alias(topics)); data.withWatermark(---).groupBy(----).count(); query = data.writeStream().format("parquet").option("path",---).option("truncate", "false").outputMode("append").option("checkpointLocation", checkpointFile).start();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since each query is running independently from the others you need to ensure you're giving each query enough resources to execute. What could be happening is if you're using the default [FIFO scheduler](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#scheduling-within-an-application) then all triggers are running sequentially vs in parallel.

Just as described [here](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/structured-streaming/production.html#configuring-spark-scheduler-pools-for-efficiency) you should set a [FAIR scheduler](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#fair-scheduler-pools) on your SparkContext and then define new pools for each query.

```
// Run streaming query1 in scheduler pool1
spark.sparkContext.setLocalProperty("spark.scheduler.pool", "pool1")
df.writeStream.queryName("query1").format("parquet").start(path1)

// Run streaming query2 in scheduler pool2
spark.sparkContext.setLocalProperty("spark.scheduler.pool", "pool2")
df.writeStream.queryName("query2").format("orc").start(path2)
```

Also, in terms of purging old parquet files you may want to partition the data and then periodically delete old partitions as needed. Otherwise you can't just delete rows if all the data is being written to the same output path.

Comment: Thank you. Fair scheduler perfectly solved my problem. Is it possible for me to delete the snappy.parquet files which are older than x days?

Comment: You mean deleting the parquet files within a folder? For that you would need to use the HDFS APIs directly since Spark doesn't give you a method to delete individual files.

Comment: yes. I store files in Google cloud storage. I can use Google APIs to delete the older files. I am not sure if it will create any different problems. Can I understand that parquet files are just like normal files and deleting the older files wouldn't cause any problems in newer data?

Comment: I am planning to create a Google cloud storage bucket which will retain only last 2 days of files.

Comment: It might cause problems if you're actively querying the data and they get deleted. So maybe try to delete them when you know you're least likely to be running queries.

Comment: Thanks. I will try.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it helped your resolve the issues you were having, thanks!